# Запрос числовых и текстовых значений в текстовом поле PostgreSQL

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql

Mysql выполняет запрос в текстовом поле по цифровым (больше и меньше) и текстовым значениям. Как сделать такое же в PostgreSQL?

Есть информация в столбце `OFFER`:

```
0,58 
10,07 
1,4 
240 
0,21 не обнаружены
5,5 
71,6 
 Отрицательно
 Отрицательно
 Отрицательно
0 
 Отрицательно
0 
 Следы
0,5 
 Отрицательно
 Отрицательно
1,015 
 Полная
76,9 
0 
 Норма
```

Вот запрос SQL работающий на MySQL

```
select analiz.oms, analiz.test, analiz.offer, analiz.date_rezult 
FROM analiz 
left JOIN prikrc on analiz.oms = prikrc.oms
WHERE 
 (
(test LIKE 'ca 125%' AND offer > 35)
   OR (test LIKE 'eos' AND offer > 1)
   OR (test LIKE 'HbA1c' AND offer > 10)
   OR (test LIKE 'LYM' AND (offer < 1 OR offer > 8) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'NEU' AND (offer < 1 OR offer > 15) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'HGB' AND (offer < 105 or offer > 190) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки%')
   OR (test LIKE 'plt' AND (offer < 50 OR offer > 750) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'RPR Treponema pallidum' AND offer LIKE 'Положительный')
   OR (test LIKE 'WBC' AND (offer < 3 OR offer > 15) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'Аланинаминотрасфераза (Алат)' AND offer > 120)
```

Я пробовал сделать данный запрос через Python
Данный запрос не выполняется
Прошу подсказать как можно решить данный вопрос на Postgresql или PYthon (может какой нибудь библиотекой)

Comment: То есть `offer` - это текстовый столбец, при этом вы одновременно и текст в нём ищете и числа с ним сравниваете? Возможно, нужно попытаться сконвертировать значение столбца в число и тогда уже пытаться с числами сравнивать. Да, и добавьте в вопрос, что значит "через Python Данный запрос не выполняется". Если выходит ошибка - добавьте ошибку в вопрос. И покажите в вопросе код, которым вы выполняете данный запрос, возможно вы где-то ошиблись и в коде.

Comment: Да все верно, столбец OFFER - это текстовый столбец 
при выполнение на postgresql - ругается что столбец не числовой. 
Python нашел библиотеку from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
но ее не удается пока подключить в pycharm

Comment: Spark - это совсем отдельная штука, у вас есть он вообще, зачем вам библиотека для spark?

Comment: нет, вот стараюсь его установить - но пока все безуспешно

Comment: Если вы не знаете, что такое spark, то скорее всего вам он не нужен. И питоновская библиотека для спарк - это только коннектор к нему. Сам spark нужно отдельно ещё устанавливать, это очень непростое дело.

Comment: Да, вот тут полностью согласен

Мне самое главное заставить работать данный скрипт через Postgresql , что вряд ли возможно.
Видимо теперь остается только python и что то еще для обработки информации

Comment: Сделайте в запросе преобразование `to_number(case when offer ~ '[0-9]' then offer end, '-1')` и дальше сравнивайте то, что получилось, с числами. -1 будет означать, что число не найдено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше, конечно, в базе выделить цифровое значение в отдельную колонку.
Например (0.21,'Не обнаружено')

В текущем виде можно попробовать так

```
select *
  ,case when regexp_instr(split_part(trim(offer),' ',1),'[^ 0123456789,.]')=0
    then cast(replace('0'||split_part(trim(offer),' ',1),',','.') as float)
   else 0 end offerV
from analiz
```

То есть, Ваш запрос может выглядеть так

```
select analiz.oms, analiz.test, analiz.offer, analiz.date_rezult 
FROM (
  select *
    ,case when regexp_instr(split_part(trim(offer),' ',1),'[^ 0123456789,.]')=0
       then cast(replace('0'||split_part(trim(offer),' ',1),',','.') as float)
     else 0 end offerV
     from analiz
    ) analiz 
left JOIN prikrc on analiz.oms = prikrc.oms
WHERE 
 (
(test LIKE 'ca 125%' AND offerV > 35)
   OR (test LIKE 'eos' AND offerV > 1)
   OR (test LIKE 'HbA1c' AND offerV > 10)
   OR (test LIKE 'LYM' AND (offerV < 1 OR offerV > 8) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'NEU' AND (offerV < 1 OR offerV > 15) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'HGB' AND (offerV < 105 or offerV > 190) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки%')
   OR (test LIKE 'plt' AND (offerV < 50 OR offerV > 750) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'RPR Treponema pallidum' AND offer LIKE 'Положительный')
   OR (test LIKE 'WBC' AND (offerV < 3 OR offerV > 15) and  offer not LIKE '%сгустки %')
   OR (test LIKE 'Аланинаминотрасфераза (Алат)' AND offerV > 120)
```